# 32 bit application cant find DSN or Drivers on 64 bit Windows Server

Tags: sql-server, odbc, 32bit-64bit, dsn

I have a 32bit application running on 64bit windows utilising DSN to connect to a MS SQL database. I'm getting the following error message:

Data Source Name not found

I've searched around a lot for this error and made sure I've done the basics like adding the DSN using both the 32bit and 64bit ODBC administrators. I've also tested the DSNs individually and they all connect succesfully.

Could it be possible that the application is looking in the wrong place? But then I've defined the DSN in both 64bit and 32bit so I'm stuck here.

Comment: I had a similar issue to this and I believe they re-installed the drivers using one which had an innate 64bit to 32bit conversion. I didn't implement the fix myself so I can't say where they got it from, but it may be a new direction to research until someone gives a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a Process Monitor (sysinternals tool) trace to see what the app is looking for. System DSNs are stored in the registry so if it's looking up a DSN you should see it manifest in the trace.